# Lenovo stuck on BIOS update "Update system program"

Tags: bios, freeze, updates, thinkpad

My Lenovo Thinkpad T520 had never had a BIOS update so I [downloaded the update](http://support.lenovo.com/ca/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t520/downloads/DS018809), burned it on CD and booted on it, finally getting this screen:

[image: Update system program]

**PROBLEM:** Whatever item I press "Enter" on, after a few seconds of searching the CD it stops doing anything, and stays like frozen. Arrows/F1/F3 do not do anything. Waiting for an hour does not change anything. According to [the README](https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles/8auj26uc.txt), these 3 items lead to other menus, so it is safe to think that actual BIOS update has not been initiated. So after waiting an hour I had to force reboot.

**QUESTION:** How to apply the BIOS update successfully?

*The laptop is out of warranty.*

Comment: Reburn the disc or Try booting the cd using a usb cd-dvd drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CD drives and burnt disks are often not reliable.
Better use a USB stick.

Here is how to burn a Lenovo BIOS update to a USB stick using geteltorito and dd on Linux:
https://askubuntu.com/a/651293/4066

Answer (score 0):

Use advise from other answer - use usb stick, or burn another CD **on minimal speed** and **with integrity check enabled**.